# How to cause an error 77 EBADFD in Linux

Tags: shell-script, scripting, error-handling

What's a quick shell script, Python script, or C program that can be written to cause it to exit with error code 77 i.e. EBADFD? I don't want to just say for example exit 77, I want it to do something to cause that error to actually be generated.

Comment: It's not an error, it's a return value, and will be the same via the shell code `exit 77` or assembly `mov rdi,77  mov rax,60  syscall` (for NASM and 64-bit linux).

Comment: Those are direct ways to force the return value, but is there any other way that a script would return this value? For example, `ls foo` will have a return value of 2 if the file foo is not found.

Comment: the return values of `ls` are decided by the program itself, they don't correspond to the errors returned by any system calls. Even if you might get `ls` to return 2, which happens to be the same number as `ENOENT`, it's just a coincidence. `ls` will return >0 if any error occurs, and returning a 2 in certain cases is a feature of GNU ls. Some others will just return a 1 on any error, and returning a non-zero value is the [only thing required](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/ls.html).

Comment: Radiation could flip bits in `rdi` at the right moment or with `gdb` you could make the value whatever or if someone uses `EX_NOPERM` of `sysexits(3)` the exit could be 77. Same difference from doing `exit 77` or whatever.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`EBADFD` is an error code that can be returned in the `errno` variable by some system calls in Linux. Anything you use in a shell's `exit 123` or `exit(123)` in a C program sets the exit status of your program.

Those aren't the same, usually a program will not exit with the error code of a system call, but something more generic, like just `1`, or with a value defined by the program itself. E.g. GNU ls returns 2 if there is an error with the files named on the command line, and a 1 if there is an error with other files encountered; [`sox`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/sox) on the other hand will return a 1 if the command line arguments are in error, and a 2 if it faces an error with files.

As for `EBADFD`, it doesn't seem to be very common, mostly used in some drivers, with sound drivers seemingly being a somewhat prominent user ([see here](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/ident?i=EBADFD)). (`EBADF` would be common, of course.)